# Leaflet with Edge Canary (recent version) mouse and markers glitch gap shift

Tags: leaflet, cursor, microsoft-edge, marker

With recent release of Microsoft Edge Canary version (as of date 2/May/2022, version 102.0.1243.0)
it seems like when moving the mouse it is and hovering over a marker there is a gap between the place of the marker and the mouse location.

As can be seen here, if you move the mouse in the borders of the marker, the cursor icon will change between finger and hand mode in the wrong location

https://codesandbox.io/s/canaryleaflet-forked-nu5vdx

Need to try this using Microsoft Edge Canary version (I am forced to use Ms.Edge browser). It works ok using Google Chrome.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a cross-post of https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/8208